# unable to compress some hidden folders of old OS

Tags: compression, hidden-files

I am trying (in Ubuntu 15.05) to compress some folders related to my older versions of OS (Ubuntu 14.10). If I try to compress these folders with "right click > Compress" it gives following error:

[image]

I have try compressing with other tools like tar, 7z and zip, but not results.

When I try to do same with command line (so that any error message may get generated) the following is absorbed:

```
$ zip -r install_files.zip ./install_files/*
zip warning: name not matched: ./install_files/adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Cert/curl-ca-bundle.crt
zip warning: name not matched: ./install_files/cache/plainbox/sessions/last-session
zip warning: name not matched: ./install_files/config/pulse/9dd80433128ff55181cc339354be9510-runtime
```

I have also renames these folders stating with '.foo' with 'foo', but no use. I cannot make out these warning messages, any help in this regards?

Comment: what command did you use?

Comment: $ zip -r install_files.zip ./install_files/*

Comment: did you check if these files are actually present or are they symlinks?

Comment: I think you are right about symlinks, I never new what there are but found somthing [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/265675/how-can-i-zip-compress-a-symlink). Using option --symlink the command ran and zip file is generated.

Comment: but what is these files to do with compressing these file?

Comment: Could you please rephrase this last question? I’m not sure what you mean …

Comment: I think the symlinks are also a kind of files. why would the compress operation through any warning if the actual files are missing? is there any reason for such behaviour?

Comment: Answering to my above query: programs that read or write to files named by a symbolic link will behave as if operating directly on the target file [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). So the compress program also try to read the target file/folder itself and in my case since target do not exits, I am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder which is to be compressed contains a symbolic link in it, with symbolic link's target is missing then the compress operation will fail.

Symbolic link: Symbolic link is a special type of file that contains a reference to another file or directory in the form of an absolute or relative path and that affects pathname resolution. The programs that read or write to files named by a symbolic link will behave as if operating directly on the "target".

The "target": is a file or directory that a symbolic link contains in form of text string that is automatically interpreted and followed by the operating system as a path.

If there is a need to compress in such a case then we can use command line and give options to include "symbolic link" them self instead of target. For example in case of "zip" use "--symlink" in the command.